# How to minimize response time for requests

Tags: php, httpresponse, cakephp

I've been using CakePHP for a while now. It is very easy and great to work on projects of wide range. I've been doing most of heavy calculations and database access in controller function. And only using the views to display the data which user is interested in. It has been working great till now. And no problem has occured. 
But I want to ask is that, "Is it a right way to work with a framework in PHP. Is there any other way i can minimize the time required to process the request.
Thank You.

Comment: Yes, you can write your own system, optimized for your particular needs. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Without seeing code its hard to help really and know what it is that need optimising.

Answer (score -1):

### APC

The easiest way to improve your performance is to use(install) [APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator). APC helps you improve performance by precompiling bytecode and store it in memory(memory is fast). If you are on a shared hosting provider you haven't got the luxury to do this, but then again if your site gets big and receives a lot of traffic you should move away from shared hosting. You should buy a VPS and if your site gets even too big for this you should buy decided machine for hosting. The final solution if you are getting really big you should run/buy a cloud system.

### CACHE

Next you should **CACHE** your data in memory to speed up your site again using APC. If your site gets big and one box doesn't cut it anymore you should cache your data in for example [redis](http://redis.io) or [memcached](http://memcached.org). Some people also start with using redis/memcached from the beginning. For example redis(FAST => KICKASS) is also a very powerful in  memory database.

### Low hanging fruit

After that you should benchmark your site using a tool like for example siege and tackle the low hanging fruit(don't wast your time doing [silly micro-optimizations](http://www.brandonsavage.net/micro-optimizations-that-dont-matter/)) by using a tool like for example valgrind/calgrind. This video ["Simple is Hard" from Rasmus lerdorf(PHP creator)](http://www.archive.org/details/simple_is_hard) explains how he achieves this.

### CakePHP Benchmarks

As a sidenote I would also like to point out that Rasmus Lerdorf(PHP creator) performed some [benchmarks](http://talks.php.net/show/drupal08/25) on CakePHP(CakePHP 1.2.0rc2) in the past and experienced it was slow as hell(Could have changed because the benchmarks have been performed in 2008 or something). but I thought these slides where really interesting. Based on the slides I would recommend you to switch to Codeigniter(the lighter your framework is the better your performance is going to be) as your framework.

Comment: you can a) use OpCodeCache, b) use MemCache, c) use LazyLoading, d) use a good webserver with high performance and maybe not apache but nginx running on it. This way, your cake site is as fast as with any other framework.

Comment: @Mark have you even looked at the slides. Cakephp used to be slow as helllllll!

Comment: depends on what your objectives are.  No frameworks will be as fast as code without a framework.  Those slides are from Cake 1.2.  1.3 saw some significant performance boosts.  I think Cake is still the slowest of the PHP frameworks, but it's within a reasonable range of other frameworks.